# Shift text after cursor to specified column

Tags: text-editing, comment, align

If I have a line like:

`vec3 pos; // May not be defined.`

And I want to shift the comment to a specific column number, say 27, such that I get:

`vec3 pos;                  // May not be defined.`

Is there a single command that can do this if I have the cursor placed just before the comment?

If not, what is the easiest way to achieve this affect?

I will be doing this regularly to keep comments aligned, so a quick and generic solution is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set comment-column to whatever you want:

```
(setq comment-column 27)       ;it's 32 by default for javascript
```

Then `M ;` (bound to `comment-dwim`) will do it.

Comment: `C-c ;` isn't defined in my setup. What is the command name? Edit: Seems to be `indent-for-comment`. Please correct me if I am mistaken though.

Comment: Sorry - it should be `M-;` which is bound to `comment-dwim` - I don't know what I was thinking. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Been using Emacs for almost 7 years and didn't know about this feature! X-D Thanks much.